# Which framework/CMS/... choose for a "repository" website

Tags: html, frameworks, content-management-system, repository

I want to create a nice (and modern?) site where media will be available for registered users. Audio, video, document, image... some kind of repository.

Users can see and download data.

Does it exist some specific solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost any CMS nowadays has media library module. Drupal, Wordpress MODx,  all of those has it, one way or another.

Comment: Do you know any example? Thank you :) I want to order the content, see a list, download, view...

Comment: I already gave you three! Drupal, Wordpress, MODx

Comment: Sorry, no CMS examples, I mean sites...

Comment: Here is link to description of Wordpress feature https://codex.wordpress.org/Media_Library_Screen

Comment: All of named CMS support theming so design can be literaly anything